# Is the copper wire the grounding wire? doorbell transformer

Tags: doorbell, transformer

[image]

I just got a Eufy doorbell and apparently I have to change the transformer. I got the upgraded transformer and saw some videos on it saying just to connect the white to the white, black to the black, and green to the green. My old transformer only has two wires connected to it on the back and there is no green wire, only white and black. Is that loose copper wire the ground wire and should I connect it to the green wire on the new transformer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes that bare copper wire at the bottom of the electrical box is the safety ground. You should check closely in the box. The bare copper wires from both electrical cables entering from the top-back of the box are supposed to be connected together. Often these are connected via a small crimp on copper sleeve with one of the two wires sticking out as the one you can see in the picture.